# NVMe drives shows in lscpi but not on lsblk

Tags: nvme, lspci

I have two NVMe drives installed on my motherboard but only one appears when executing `lsblk` as follows

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1 259:0   0   234G  0 disk
```

I can see both of them when executing lspci so the system its able to recognized them in its root complex but not as a disk. It list them as follow:

---

**First:**

```
9c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 0100
```

---

**Second:**

```
a8:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801 (rev 01)
```

---

Any guess?

Thanks!